# Active Admin nested model with existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I want to use nested models.
I got a group and student models, a group has_many students.
What I want to do is when I create a group be able to add existing students in the system and also be able to dynamicaly search for them for ex with datatables.
What I already have:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :students
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to     :group
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a join table as:-

```
rails g migration groups_students group_id:integer student_id:integer

class GroupsStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups_students, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :group_id
      t.integer :student_id
    end
  end
end
```

**In Group model**:-

```
attr_accessible :student_ids
has_and_belongs_to_many :students
accepts_nested_attributes_for :students
```

**In Student model**:-

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
```

Look the documentation of [Active admin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) and register the Group model as :-

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Group
```

In app/admin/groups.rb :-

```
form do |f|
 # f.semantic_errors
  f.inputs "Groups" do
  f.input :table_fields # To DO :: Add other fields

  f.input :students, as: :check_boxes, collection: Student.all     
end
f.actions
```

end

Comment: There's any way to add a class="example" to this table. The idea is to add jquery and custom search. Using your example I got the following error: can't write unknown attribute `group_id' the server says ....

Comment: SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "groups" ("book_id", "created_at", "date_end", "date_start", "description", "professor_id", "study_center_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["book_id", 1], ["created_at", Tue, 30 Dec 2014 03:23:53 UTC +00:00], ["date_end", Wed, 03 Dec 2014], ["date_start", Tue, 02 Dec 2014], ["description", "asdf"], ["professor_id", 1], ["study_center_id", 1], ["updated_at", Tue, 30 Dec 2014 03:23:53 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 27ms

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xGjDErtO6fXo+PUoh/baAHupKmjq/5wWjjlzIfzROGc=", "group"=>{"professor_id"=>"1", "date_start"=>"2014-12-02", "date_end"=>"2014-12-03", "study_center_id"=>"1", "book_id"=>"1", "description"=>"asdf", "student_ids"=>["", "1", "2", "3", "4"]}, "commit"=>"Save Group"}

Comment: can't write unknown attribute `group_id'